# I want to write a program that find multiplicative order in lisp but I don't know what wrong with my program

Tags: lisp

here is the definition of multiplicative order
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order

here is the program

```
    (defun power (x y)
       (if (= y 0) 1 
           (if (evenp y) (* (power x (/ y 2)) (power x (/ y 2)))
               (* x (power x (/ (- y 1) 2)) (power x (/ (- y 1) 2))))))  
(defun ord (n r)
      (if (> (gcd n r) 1) 0 
          (let ((a 0))(loop (defvar a (+ a 1)) 
               (when (= (mod (- (power r a) 1) n) 0)(return a))))))
```

Comment: I would start with better formatting. Right now your code is unreadable. Next you need to write an error description: what went wrong and how! Then you need to ask yourself if the DEFVAR construct is usefult in this context...

Comment: thanks because I'm new with lisp so there must be a lots of mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution, without the use of a `power` function (note that such a function is already defined in Common Lisp, [`expt`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_exp_e.htm#expt)).

```
(defun ord (n r)
   (if (> (gcd r n) 1)
       0
       (loop for k from 1
         for v = r then (* v r)
         when (= 1 (mod v n))
           do (return k))))
```

To calculate the multiplicative order of *a* modulo *n*, one should call the function with `(ord a n)`. For instance:

```
(ord 7 10) ; => 6
```

since 10<sup>6</sup> ≡ 1 (mod 7)

The function first checks to see if the two parameters are coprimes, otherwise it returns 0. Then the extended `loop` form is used to perform a loop over two variables, `k` (the result), starting from 1 and increasing by 1 at each iteration, and `v`, the current power of `r`, starting from `r` and increasing multiplying the preceding value by `r` at each iteration (so at each iteration the invariant is *v* = *r*<sup>*k*</sup>). When we reach the value of `k` such that  *v* mod *n* = 1, we terminate the iteration returning `k`.

For a detailed description of `loop` see either the [formal definition](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm#loop), or a practical explanation (present in chapter 7 and 22) of the really useful book [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) (a “must to read” to learn Common Lisp).

Comment: @ThuậnNguyễn, I added an explanation as well as links.